# API gateway request validation not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've created a REST API within AWS API gateway, with an OpenAPI3 spec with my methods connected to a lambda proxy integration.
For some reason, my requests are no longer validated by API gateway (which I'm like 99% sure they were before), however, I have not willingly changed anything except adding more methods to the API. Dumbed-down version of my CloudFormation `RestApi` resource:

```
"FooApi": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
  "Properties": {
    "FailOnWarnings": false,
    "Name": "foo-api",
    "EndpointConfiguration": {
      "Types": [
        "EDGE"
      ]
    },
    "BinaryMediaTypes": [
      "*/*"
    ],
    "Body": {
      "openapi": "3.0.2",
      ... <info, components etc retracted from example>
      "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators": {
        "all": {
          "validateRequestBody": true,
          "validateRequestParameters": true
        }
      },
      "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator": "all"
      "paths": {
        "/foos":
          "post": {
            "operationId": "addFoo",
            "requestBody": {
              "required": true,
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [
                      "bar"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "bar": {
                        "type": string
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  ...
```

As seen, I specify `x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator` on the API level with a value of `all`, which is mapped to a validator which should validate both bodies and parameters. However, when I make `POST` requests to `/foos` and do not supply any request body, or if I do supply a request body such as `{}`, I do not get any request validation errors. Instead, the request reaches the proxy integration lambda function where `event.body` is null or `{}`, respectively.

How do I enable request validation so that missing or invalid bodies or parameters render `BAD_REQUEST` responses?

Comment: Does the validation work from the Test tab in AWS console? Did you deploy your API (using the `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` resource or otherwise)?